# Good (and recent) resource for expert systems

Tags: artificial-intelligence, expert-system, fuzzy-logic

Does anyone know any good (and recent) resources for designing expert systems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is not much recent development in expert systems. This [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0534384471) is a classic (last edition is from 2004).

Comment: Yes, I was looking for a resource and most of the resources were from 90's. and I really had no idea which one is better. This one seems recent enough. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

we are taking an Expert systems course in our college and we are using this book :

- [Artificial Intelligence: A Guide to Intelligent Systems](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201711591)

and using Clips Language for programming expert systems 
the book is pretty Good and discussing Modern topics ( see the latest version ) 
and it introduces well the parts related to fuzzy logic and neural networks which is related to ExpertSystems .

i recommend starting exploration from the internet and the book for some time 
then start knowing the science from the book and implement using the CLIPS language

- [Clips tutorials](http://iweb.tntech.edu/bhuguenard/ds6530/ClipsTutorial/tableOfContents.htm)

Comment: I'm not aware of any recent published texts dealing specifically with expert systems but papers are still being published so you probably want to occasionally do a literature search in arxiv or other sources.  Basically since around 2010 (really a bit before) symbolic problem solving systems became deprecated in favor of connectionist systems.  If you do a literature search be aware that some 1/4-1/3 or so of most papers cover basic material before presenting their innovations and architecture.